# use Entity Framework to connect to 2 dbs

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

My question is pretty simple, we are using Entity Framework 5 and use the standard setup.  We are in the middle of moving servers around the country, and need a period where all db transactions ( insert, update ) to do the exact same thing to two different connection strings.  Both databases will be identical and the purpose of this is to keep them identical.

Is there any way to set up Entity Framework's DbContext to connect to multiple connection strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to set up Entity Framework's DbContext to connect to multiple connection strings?

No, this is not possible.

Consider setting up replication between the two servers instead.

> We are in the middle of moving servers around the country

Note that replication can catch up if one of the servers becomes available for some period of time.

Comment: I pretty much knew that answer, but was hoping there was some stupid little hack.  Couldn't there be some type of override in the DbContext to tell it to go to one connection string , then tell it to do the same on another?

Comment: @ScottSelby Sure there _could_ be.  They could also code in an option to translate all English words to German.  This is an _edge case_ - frameworks are build for general use, not edge cases.

Comment: ok, basically I just needed one guy with 94k rep and another with 84k rep to agree with me telling IT this is a stupid idea

Comment: @ScottSelby: Stupid or  not isn't the issue.  It is not possible to accomplish that with Entity Framework.  IT will just have to use a tool they already have at their disposal, which is the tried-and-true technology of database replication.

Comment: but also .... it's a stupid idea to find every spot in the code that uses an instance of a specific DbContext and add code to connect to another , no to mention that some spots in code use UnitOfWork pattern and some go directly to DbConetext

Comment: you could override the save changes in your dbcontext, to call another save changes on another EF which would be a loose copy of the first with a different connection string

Comment: @johnny5: The amount of work involved in getting that right, for production use, is enormous.

Comment: @ScottSelby: Is your IT department seriously suggesting that you completely rewrite the code to support this migration?  The programming and QA effort to do that is enormous for any non-trivial application.

Comment: Yes they were suggesting that I do that, and I said no, I felt it appropiate to come and get a third opinion on here before I stuck with my initial response now feeling a little better .  In the end I got my way , we are using mirroring/replication on the db